# Can't update data when value is assigned to textboxes in load page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

My problem is probably stupid due to my inexperience to programming but please help.

So, I set some textboxes to values from my other page so the user can edit their Task and see what their task was original and edit from there.

The problem is that I set those values in **Page Load** so when I tried to update it, it updated the original value not the new one that entered because the page load return the old value. Because of this I cannot update my database to new value.

Is there anyway to approaches this problem or to fix this? Like should I place the code somewhere else?

**Edit:** Ok so I did some more research and found that my problem could maybe be solved by using IsPostBack but I don't understand how to use this code. The only thing I kinda understand is that it is used to return the page to before it got refresh by page load?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Session("Editing") IsNot Nothing Then

        btnCreate.Visible = False
        btnEdit.Visible = True
        Dim Form As FormViewRow = CType(Session("Editing"), FormViewRow) 'get data from the the formview in Home page

        Dim Title As Label = CType(Form.FindControl("TitleLabel"), Label)
        txtTitle.Text = Title.Text

        Dim description As Label = CType(Form.FindControl("DescriptionLabel"), Label)
        txtDescription.Text = description.Text

        Dim diff As Label = CType(Form.FindControl("DifficultyLabel"), Label)
        ddlDifficulty.Text = diff.Text

        Dim taskID As Label = CType(Form.FindControl("IDLabel"), Label)
        Dim whatID As String = taskID.Text
        Session("EditTaskID") = taskID.Text

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I was just playing around with IsPostBack and managed to get it to work.

All I did was put my code in an If statement IsPostBack is not equal True Then... Since I'm still learning can someone explain the meaning of IsPostBack in the simplest terms?

It's fine if no one explain it to me. My problem is solved and thank you Amin for taking your time trying to help me.   (:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    If IsPostBack <> True Then

        If Session("Editing") IsNot Nothing Then
            btnCreate.Visible = False
            btnEdit.Visible = True

            Dim Form As FormViewRow = CType(Session("Editing"), FormViewRow) 'get data from the the formview in Home page

            Dim Title As Label = CType(Form.FindControl("TitleLabel"), Label)
            txtTitle.Text = Title.Text

            Dim description As Label = CType(Form.FindControl("DescriptionLabel"), Label)
            txtDescription.Text = description.Text

            Dim diff As Label = CType(Form.FindControl("DifficultyLabel"), Label)
            ddlDifficulty.Text = diff.Text

            Dim taskID As Label = CType(Form.FindControl("IDLabel"), Label)
            Dim whatID As String = taskID.Text
            Session("EditTaskID") = taskID.Text

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your editing page is opened in the same window or a new one. In first scenario, you can save edited values somewhere like `Session` and restore them in main page's `Page_Load` server event. According to 2nd scenario, you can use some simple `javascript` codes to reflex data changes to main page.

Comment: The page that I'm on is also my create page. The reason I choose to do this is because the edit in my formview from my other page doesnt update values from different forms (dropdown list, checkbox, calender etc). How would i save edited values? And I don't know much about javascript on ASP.NET. It wasnt my first programming language so I would have great problem with that even if its simple.